# ios совместимый с xcode 4.7

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone

Доброго времени суток!
Написал приложение для `iphone` и скомпилировал его на симуляторе. 
Среда разработки - `xcode 4.7` Симулятор использует версию `iphone 6.1` (я не знаю какая версия `ios` соответствует этому). 
Скажите пожалуйста:

1. Какие `iphone`'ы (с какой версией `ios`) можно купить, чтобы собрать приложение с такой версией?
2. Можно ли брать `ipad touch` (вместо `iphone`) и не возникнет ли потом подводных камней?

**UPDATE**

1. Вопросы совместимости `xcode` и `ios` исчерпывающе пояснены в [википедии.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Version_comparison_table)
2. `Ipоd` `touch` при равных версиях `ios` проигрывает `iphone` по железу: имеет более низкую оперативную память, и более низкую частоту процессора. Сравнение по возможностям [айфонов](http://appstudio.org/iphone), [aйпод тачей](http://appstudio.org/ipodtouch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) iphone 6.1 это и есть iphone с ios версии 6.1

2) кроме очевидных различий ( нельзя звонить, писать текстовые сообщения и т.д.) других проблем быть не должно

Answer (score 1):

Можешь купить iPhone3GS, для него последняя прошивка - 6.13.
Можно использовать и iPod и iPad. Если не используешь ничего специализированного (настоящий gps, 3G и тд). В некоторых железяках этого нет.

Вот еще пара полезных таблиц:

http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-FRbS8GJsuqc/VJa7YpJ1pnI/AAAAAAAACPs/1uv0zB1oFZI/s1600/Screen%2BShot%2B2014-12-21%2Bat%2B5.49.37%2Bpm.png

http://lowendmac.com/wp-content/uploads/support-idevice.png